# VLAN Subnetting Ruckus and Fortigate and Cisco

Tags: ip, vlan

This is an easy solution, I just don't have it, so please help!

I have 6 Ruckus R500 WAP, connected into 2 Cisco SG300's, which are then connected to  FortiGate 200D.

On the WAP, I have 5 SSID, one of which is set to VLAN 2.

The ports which the WAP connect to on the SG300's have VLAN 2 added to them, trunk mode.

In the FortiGate200D:

All ports are in LAN HW Switch. 
**IP: 10.3.7.210/255.255.252.0 
DHCP 10.3.4.1-10.3.5.254**

I have a VLAN sub created on the LAN, with an Id of 2. 
**IP: 10.3.9.1/255.255.255.0 
DHCP 10.3.9.2-254**

There are "auto" routes created for 10.3.9.0/24 --> 0.0.0.0

When I connect to the VLAN 2 SSID, I am unable to pull an IP. If I set static IP, I am unable to ping. Where am I messed up? Is it because my LAN HW Switch subnet does not contain 10.3.9.xxx ? What would the best way to overcome this be, perhaps change LAN HW Switch to 10.3.0.0/21?

Basically the end goal is 10.3.4.0 and 10.3.5.0 for normal connections. And then a separate subnet for VLAN2, could be 10.3.8.0 or 10.3.9.0 or whatever, even 192.168.1.0.

Comment: The SG300 ports connecting the Fortigate need VLAN 2 (tagged) as well. Where do you route the VLAN subnets? Where's your DHCP server?

Comment: Ok, I did not have the ports going to the Fortinet tagged, I have tagged them. My DHCP server is configured on the LAN Sub VLAN Zone in the FortiGate, and is set to distribute 10.3.9.2-254.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by Zac67. I had to correct tagging, then open up traffic to WAN and DHCP kicked in just fine. Thanks Zac67